# What is the difference between BTAHL72x and BTAHL72XML send and recieve pipelines?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, btahl7

I am not sure about when should we use BTAHL72x instead of BTAHL72XML send/receive pipelines in biztalk and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The BTAHL72XReceive/BTAHL72XSend pipelines are for parse and serialize the Flat File messages.

For XML messages then you have to use the BTAHL72XML pipelines.